# How can create summary footer on runtime?

Tags: delphi, runtime, footer, tcxgrid

I use TcxGrid I have create fields on execution time because I have a pivot query and columns are variable

I filled my grid like theese codes

```
grdCevapDBTableView2.BeginUpdate;
grdCevapDBTableView2.ClearItems;
fillGridView(grdCevapDBTableView2,command);
grdCevapDBTableView2.DataController.CreateAllItems;
grdCevapDBTableView2.EndUpdate;
```

Now I want to get sum values from these columns. How can create summary footer on runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say for example you had a field called cost and you wanted to summarise the total:

```
index := grdCevapDBTableView2.GetColumnByFieldName('cost').index;
grdCevapDBTableView2.Columns[index].Summary.Footerkind:=skSum;
grdCevapDBTableView2.Columns[index].Summary.FooterFormat:='£ #.##';
```

I would also stick the beginupdate and endupdate between try..finally block, ie:

```
grdCevapDBTableView2.BeginUpdate;
try       
  grdCevapDBTableView2.ClearItems;       
  fillGridView(grdCevapDBTableView2,command);       
  grdCevapDBTableView2.DataController.CreateAllItems;       
finally
  grdCevapDBTableView2.EndUpdate;   
end;
```

this just ensures that your tableview will eventually end the update and redraw.

Comment: May I add that *GridMode MUST be set to false* for the footers to work? I just found out.