# Delphi code to create TcxGrid GroupSummaries at runtime

Tags: delphi, tcxgrid

I have code that creates summary footers at runtime for numeric columns, but I can't get the group summary results to show. I've looked at [How to create group summaries at runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q449686) and [How to set group summary values](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q99383) and [How can create summary footer on runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514190/how-can-create-summary-footer-on-runtime) but I'm hitting runtime error:

> EcxInvalidDataControllerOperation with message 'RecordIndex out of range'

when the grid is rendering.

This code accepts any TcxGridDBTableView so it would be very easy to put into an existing Delphi form.

```
procedure SummaryGroup(ASummary: TcxDataSummary; AColumn: TcxGridDBColumn;
  AKind: TcxSummaryKind; AFormat: string);
var
  sumGroup: TcxDataSummaryGroup;
  link: TcxGridTableSummaryGroupItemLink; //TcxDataSummaryGroupItemLink;
  item: TcxGridDBTableSummaryItem;
begin
  AColumn.Summary.FooterKind := AKind;
  AColumn.Summary.FooterFormat := AFormat;
  sumGroup := ASummary.SummaryGroups.Add;
  link := sumGroup.Links.Add as TcxGridTableSummaryGroupItemLink;
  link.Column := AColumn;
  item := sumGroup.SummaryItems.Add as TcxGridDBTableSummaryItem;
  item.Column := AColumn;
  item.Kind := AKind;
  item.Position := spGroup;
  item.Format := AColumn.Summary.FooterFormat;
end;

procedure AutoAwesum(AView: TcxGridDBTableView);
var
  summary: TcxDataSummary;
  summing: Boolean;
  i: Integer;
  dc: TcxGridDBDataController;
  col: TcxGridDBColumn;

begin
  dc := AView.DataController;
  summing := False;
  summary := dc.Summary;
  summary.BeginUpdate;
  try
    summary.SummaryGroups.Clear;
    dc.BeginFullUpdate;
    try
      dc.GridView.ClearItems;
      dc.CreateAllItems;
      for i := 1 to AView.ColumnCount - 1 do
      begin
        col := AView.Columns[i];
        case col.DataBinding.Field.DataType of
          ftSmallint, ftInteger, ftWord, ftLargeint, ftAutoInc,
          ftLongWord, ftShortint:
            begin
              summing := true;
              SummaryGroup(summary, col, skSum, '#');
            end;
          ftFloat, ftBCD, ftFMTBcd, ftExtended, ftSingle:
            begin
              summing := true;
              SummaryGroup(summary, col, skSum, '#.##');
            end;
          ftCurrency:
            begin
              summing := true;
              SummaryGroup(summary, col, skSum, '$#.##');
            end;
        end;
      end;
      dc.DataModeController.GridMode := not summing;
      AView.OptionsView.Footer := summing;
      AView.OptionsView.GroupFooterMultiSummaries := summing;
      AView.OptionsView.GroupFooters := gfVisibleWhenExpanded;
    finally
      dc.EndFullUpdate;
    end;
  finally
    summary.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Which line is generating the exception?

Comment: it's not happening in my code. It's in the cxGrid runtime, on TcxCustomDataController.CheckRecordRange.

Comment: Then look at the stack trace, and figure out where in *your* code the exception is being triggered. If the exception is indeed not traceable to your own code, then you need to file a bug report with the vendor instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ken. As I said in my original question, the error occurs when the grid is rendering. This is after my code has set the properties on the grid (without errors). I was hoping that by providing complete, generic code that would work for any TcxGrid I could get specific pointers on what properties of the grid might be missing, rather than general advice on how to debug a problem in Delphi.

Comment: Hmmm. OK, but that again appears to be something that should be asked at the vendor's forums (isn't that a Developers Express component?) rather than here. It's pretty difficult to debug a third-party vendor's component without the code that's using that component, unless you're extremely familiar with the internal workings of that component. Can you provide a MVCE that sets the properties at runtime that produces the error? Or include the text from a DFM that sets the properties as you have them?

Comment: I've seen many other responses to TcxGrid questions here, so I thought perhaps I would encounter someone familiar with it. My code can be added to any Delphi form that has a TcxGrid and be called once the datasource is established for the grid, but debugging is of limited utility. I'll open a ticket Monday if I don't have an answer by then. I was hoping someone had already solved this problem. In the meantime I'll continue to debug it myself to see if I can navigate the code labyrinth successfully.

Comment: John: if I were you I'd ask support, but just in case I'll flag them to come take a look here. I'd also note you don't mention version numbers of the DevExpress VCL product nor of which compiler you are using, both of which might be germane.

Comment: @boyetboy thanks Julian. It'x XE4 and ExpressQuantumGrid Suite 12.1.6. I was going to ask support this week if I didn't get an answer here. FWIW, I could also use XE7 for it, but I think it would still be the same grid quite version unless we've taken an update for it. (This is a utility for me to use at WideOrbit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally had a chance to get back to this. As expected, the changes were few and simple. Here's the code that generically creates group summary headers for each numeric column in a grid. I've left some options commented out in the code that you may want to use.

```
uses
  cxGridDBDataDefinitions;

procedure Summarize(ASummary: TcxDataSummary; AColumn: TcxGridDBColumn;
  AKind: TcxSummaryKind; AFormat: string);
var
  sumGroup: TcxDataSummaryGroup;
  link: TcxGridTableSummaryGroupItemLink;
  item: TcxGridDBTableSummaryItem;
begin
  AColumn.Summary.FooterKind := AKind;
  AColumn.Summary.FooterFormat := AFormat;
  AColumn.Summary.GroupKind := AKind;
  AColumn.Summary.GroupFormat := AFormat;
  AColumn.GroupIndex := -1;
  sumGroup := ASummary.SummaryGroups.Add;
  link := sumGroup.Links.Add as TcxGridTableSummaryGroupItemLink;
  link.Column :=  AColumn;
  item := sumGroup.SummaryItems.Add as TcxGridDBTableSummaryItem;
  item.Column := AColumn;
  item.Kind := skSum;
  item.Position := spGroup;
  item.Format := AColumn.Summary.FooterFormat;
end;

procedure AutoAwesum(AView: TcxGridDBTableView);
var
  summary: TcxDataSummary;
  summing: Boolean;
  i: Integer;
  dc: TcxGridDBDataController;
  col: TcxGridDBColumn;

begin
  dc := AView.DataController;
  summing := False;
  summary := dc.Summary;
  summary.BeginUpdate;
  try
    summary.SummaryGroups.Clear;
    dc.BeginFullUpdate;
    try
      dc.GridView.ClearItems;
      dc.CreateAllItems;
      for i := 1 to AView.ColumnCount - 1 do
      begin
        col := AView.Columns[i];
        case col.DataBinding.Field.DataType of
          ftSmallint, ftInteger, ftWord, ftLargeint, ftAutoInc,
          ftLongWord, ftShortint:
            begin
              summing := true;
              Summarize(summary, col, skSum, ',0');
            end;
          ftFloat, ftBCD, ftFMTBcd, ftExtended, ftSingle:
            begin
              summing := true;
              Summarize(summary, col, skSum, ',.00');
            end;
          ftCurrency:
            begin
              summing := true;
              Summarize(summary, col, skSum, '$,0.00');
            end;
        end;
      end;
//      dc.DataModeController.GridMode := not summing;
//      AView.OptionsView.Header := summing;
      AView.OptionsView.Footer := summing;
//      AView.OptionsView.GroupFooterMultiSummaries := summing;
//      AView.OptionsView.GroupFooters := gfVisibleWhenExpanded;
    finally
      dc.EndFullUpdate;
    end;
  finally
    summary.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```